# Passing formData to Express middleware, Req.body is returning empty object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get formData from the client,

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /post_image_question:
 *   post:
 *     description: Post an image question
 *     parameters:
*       - name: question
 *         description: Object of userId and questions array
 *         type: object
 *         in: formData
 *         properties:
 *           userId:
 *             type: string
 *           questions:
 *             type: array
 *             items:
 *               type: object
 *               properties:
 *                 question_title:
 *                   type: string
 *                 question_description:
 *                   type: string
 *                 text_question:
 *                   type: string
 *                 code_snippet:
 *                   type: string
 *                 tagged_technologies:
 *                   type: string
 *                 image_question:
 *                   type: string
 *       - name: image_question
 *         description: The question in form of image
 *         type: file
 *         in: formData
 *         consumes:
 *         - multipart/form-data
  *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Success
 *       400:
 *         description:Bad Request
 *       404:
 *         description:Not Found
 *       500:
 *         description: Internal Server Error
 */
```

I am passing the data to middleware and I am logging req.body and get empty object, what I can do to get the formData and convert it to json data

this is my swagger documentation

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't tell why your client side code is failing to send the data or why your server side code is failing to parse it or even which of those is the case.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have in your index.js `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: I am just having app.use(express.json()), I am not getting formData if I pass middle ware to the router.post() but I am getting it if I remove that middleware from router.post()

Comment: FormData objects don't get encoded as JSON so that won't help.